# Provide different children if Wrap is multi-line vs single-line

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

I want to display some widgets in a `Wrap`, and if the widgets are too many to fit on one row, I want to display different widgets (more compact versions of the normal widgets).

How can I achieve this, without resorting to manual measurements of screen width and children? Is there any built-in way to do this with a `Wrap` or some other widget?

Answer (score 0):

What if with the compact version, the row is still full. Do you want to display the children in multiline then or wrap them with the next line? If it's the latter, then I think it's best to use `Wrap` from the beginning.

Another practical way is to make the child adaptable as well, by using `FittedBox` or make it scrollable horizontally by using `SingleChildScrollView` or `ListView`.

There can be other scenarios when it's better to show just 4-5 children that's enough to fit a row. Then have a button allowing user to navigate to a detail screen display all the children in a grid or list.